# Why do i have to use '_object' instead of 'object'

Tags: objective-c

In Xcode 4.6, I'm creating an array like this

```
entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

It says I can't and I have to do it this way -

```
_entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In the tutorial I'm following the former should be fine. Why isn't it here?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you have a property called `entries` that you have @synthesized to `entries`. You are probably getting a warning that you are shadowing a variable.

If you let Xcode autosynthesize the property it will create a backing store called `_entries` for you.

Alternatively, you could just write:

```
self.entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use _object only if you are overriding getter/setter methods.
"_object =" just assigns while "self.object =" calls its setter method. You must use _object to prevent from infinite loops within setter methods.